# Maximum size of count argument to TIMES prefix in NASM?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

Assembling the structure below using NASM, I get the following error:

```
test.asm:65: error: TIMES value -228 is negative
```

I.e., the value `0x104` is interpreted as a negative number.

What is the maximum size of the count argument to `TIMES` prefix in NASM, and how would I initialize the structure using only "small" counts?

```
_stWin32FindData:
istruc WIN32_FIND_DATA
at WIN32_FIND_DATA.dwFileAttributes, dd 0x00
at WIN32_FIND_DATA.ftCreationTime, times 0x08 db 0x00
at WIN32_FIND_DATA.ftLastAccessTime, times 0x08 db 0x00
at WIN32_FIND_DATA.ftLastWriteTime, times 0x08 db 0x00
at WIN32_FIND_DATA.nFileSizeHigh, dd 0x00
at WIN32_FIND_DATA.nFileSizeLow, dd 0x00
at WIN32_FIND_DATA.dwReserved0, dd 0x00
at WIN32_FIND_DATA.dwReserved1, dd 0x00
at WIN32_FIND_DATA.cFileName, times 0x104 db 0x00
at WIN32_FIND_DATA.cAlternate, times 0x0e db 0x00 
iend
```

I use NASM version 2.12.02 @ Windows 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the NASM source [here](http://www.nasm.us/pub/nasm/snapshots/latest/).

Grepping for "TIMES" finds these lines on `parser.c`:

```
result->times = value->value;
if (value->value < 0 && pass0 == 2) {
    nasm_error(ERR_NONFATAL, "TIMES value %"PRId64" is negative",
               value->value);
               result->times = 0;
}
```

Which suggest that `TIMES` takes 64-bits values, but
looking into `nasm.h` we found

```
typedef struct insn { /* an instruction itself */
    char            *label;                 /* the label defined, or NULL */

    ...

    int32_t         times;                  /* repeat count (TIMES prefix) */
    bool            forw_ref;               /* is there a forward reference? */

    ...
} insn;
```

which settle the size of the argument to 32-bits.

---

However the problem your are facing comes from the fact that `AT` is a macro that implicitly uses `TIMES` to move the the specified field.

> The function of the AT macro is to make use of the TIMES prefix to advance the assembly position to the correct point for the specified structure field, and then to declare the specified data. Therefore the structure fields must be declared in the same order as they were specified in the structure definition.

This is how `AT` is implemented

```
istruc teststruc2
 at .word, db 5
iend

..@12.strucstart:
  times (.word-teststruc2)-($-..@12.strucstart) db 0
  db 5
```

As @Nze said, `WIN32_FIND_DATA.cFileName` is defined as `TCHAR    cFileName[MAX_PATH]` and `MAX_PATH` is 32.
Since you define a `cFileName` too large, the `AT WIN32_FIND_DATA.cAlternate` has a `($-..@12.strucstart)` bigger than its offset in the struct `(.word-teststruc2)`.
Hence the error.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I will go and look in the source next time. However, I did not thought it was "readable" for a beginnner. I don't really understand your AT implementation.

Comment: @Shuzheng You never know what code there is behind a project. NASM one is pretty readable. The `AT` implementation is not mine, is from NASM. I found it by using the `-E` command line flag, that expands macros but don't process the file.  The first parenthesis computes the offset of the field `word` relative to the start of the structure, the second one computes the current position relative to the start of the structure instance. The difference is the number of bytes to pad to reach the `word` field.

Answer (score 1):

In the WIN32N.inc found on the web, `MAX_PATH` is defined as follows:

```
...
DDD_RAW_TARGET_PATH equ 1h
DDD_REMOVE_DEFINITION equ 2h
DDD_EXACT_MATCH_ON_REMOVE equ 4h
MAX_PATH equ 32
MOVEFILE_REPLACE_EXISTING equ 1h
MOVEFILE_COPY_ALLOWED equ 2h
...
```

Also, `WIN32_FIND_DATA.cFileName` (part of the `WIN32_FIND_DATA` structure found in the same file) is defined as having size `MAX_PATH`.

The hex value 0x104, which you specify as count argument to `TIMES`, has decimal representation 260, and we see that 32 - 260 = -228.

I cannot say why NASM interprets 0x104 as -228 (except for the calculation above), but it probably has something to do with proceeding to the next field of the structure.

However, changing the definition of `MAX_PATH` to 260 (in WIN32N.inc), the structure assembles just fine.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer.